# Mobile styling error

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have this code which causes an styling error on the mobile version:

CSS:

```
.medarbetare-img {
width: 180px;
height: 100px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
margin-top: 16px;
```

HTML:

```
<div class="left">
    <div class="medarbetare-img" style="background:
        url(http://byggprojektoren.se/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Rinor2.jpg)
        center top no-repeat;">
    </div>
    <p style="font-size:13px;">Name Name<br>
        Konstruktör, VD,delägare<br>
        <a style="font-size:13px;"href="mailto:@byggprojektoren.se">@byggprojektoren.se</a>
        <br>0762 - 92 23 51
    </p>
</div>

<div class="right">
    <p style="text-align:justify; font-size:13px; padding:10px 0;">
        Text that collides with the picture
    </p>
</div>
```

The following picture being created is:

[image: Picture]

Comment: you need to give your `img` a percentage width if you want it to shrink with the screen size.

Comment: Please make a jsfiddle with the code in it. I presume you don't want that big gap above the picture either...

Comment: @Jmh2013 How can I do that?

Comment: @alarmed alien, How can I adjust that?

Comment: @RinorM Update this fiddle with your code and post the url - http://jsfiddle.net/82md270k/

Comment: @MaryMelody, I tried you solution but now the text falls below instead of right to the picture. URL: http://byggprojektoren.se/om-oss/

Comment: instead of using `width: 180px` change it to something like `width: 50%`. Then it will only take up half of its container.

Comment: Yes I see. If you go to the url: http://byggprojektoren.se/om-oss/ you can see that the text that is to the "Right" is not all the way  to the right of the page. How come? What have I written wrong in the code? thank you

Comment: I managed to fix it with jsfiddle. I just corrected in the CSS code where it says `width:45%`